# Empty CSV file when writing lots of data

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am currently conducting a data scraping project with Python 3 and am attempting to write the scraped data to a CSV file. My current process to do it is this:

```
import csv

outputFile = csv.writer(open('myFilepath', 'w'))
outputFile.writerow(['header1', 'header2'...])
for each in data:
     scrapedData = scrap(each)
     outputFile.writerow([scrapedData.get('header1', 'header 1 NA'), ...])
```

Once this script is finished, however, the CSV file is blank. If I just run:

```
import csv

outputFile = csv.writer(open('myFilepath', 'w'))
outputFile.writerow(['header1', 'header2'...])
```

a CSV file is produced containing the headers:

```
header1,header2,..
```

If I just scrape 1 in `data`, for example:

```
outputFile.writerow(['header1', 'header2'...])
scrapedData = scrap(data[0])
outputFile.writerow([scrapedData.get('header1', 'header 1 NA'), ...])
```

a CSV file will be created including both the headers and the data for `data[0]`:

```
header1,header2,..
header1 data for data[0], header1 data for data[0]
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Try using a context manager. You are never closing your file, so it might not be flushing. A context manager should always be used when working with files, anyway.

Comment: You have to close the file after you finished writing into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a file with `w`, it erases the previous data

> From the docs
>
> > w: open for writing, truncating the file first

So when you open the file after writing scrape data with `w`, you just get a blank file and then you write the header on it so you only see the header. Try replacing `w` with `a`. So the new call to open the file would look like

`outputFile = csv.writer(open('myFilepath', 'a'))`

You can fine more information about the modes to open the file [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Ref: [How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

**Edit after DYZ's comment:**

You should also be closing the file after you are done appending. I would suggest using the file like the:

```
with open('path/to/file', 'a') as file:
    outputFile = csv.writer(file)
    # Do your work with the file
```

This way you don't have to worry about remembering to close it. Once the code exists the `with` block, the file will be closed.

Comment: The OP is not appending to the file. They open it just once. The problem is with them not closing the file.

Comment: I will update the answer. Good catch. OP still needs to be using the correct mode otherwise the problem would still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
headers = ['header1', 'header2', ...]
scraped_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
scraped_df.to_csv('filepath.csv')
```

Here I'm assuming your `data` object is a list of lists.